# Adding data in a custom database table for paid orders in WooCommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

When the user buy a product, I want to save a series of data in custom tables in database. This data will be the product id, custom fields I have, and some other data.

My idea is that this should be done when the payment of the product has been made correctly, that is to say, at the time of payment.

I wanted you to give me advice, I have created a way but I don't know if it is the right one or if you would recommend any other way.

I've edited the thankyou page, and I have inserted this code:

```
$order = new WC_Order ($order->get_id ();
$check_payment = $order->payment_complete ();

if ($check_payment) {
    global $wpdb;
    wpdb->insert (/* CODE DATABASE*/);
}
```

Comment: With a **cheque** payment method you will use the **2nd function** (as I mention it on my answer) ... I have maid an update giving you the other hooks related to processing and on-hold statuses…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As woocommerce Order-received (thankyou) page can be reloaded, it's not really the good way.

The correct hook to be used that you can find inside `WC_Order` `payment_complete()` method is `woocommerce_payment_complete`. So your code should be for most payment gateways:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'action_payment_complete', 30, 1 );
function action_payment_complete( $order_id ){
    global $wpdb;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object (if needed)
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Your database actions code
    wpdb->insert (/* CODE DATABASE*/);
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

---

For payment methods *(**CHEQUE HERE**)* as **'cheque'**, 'bacs' and 'cod' that needs to be "completed" by shop manager, you will use instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'action_order_status_completed', 20, 2 );
function action_payment_complete( $order_id, $order ){
    // The specific payment methods to be target
    $payment_methods = array('bacs','cheque','cod');

    // Only for specific payment methods
    if( ! in_array( $order->get_payment_method(), $payment_methods ) return;

    global $wpdb;

    // Your database actions code
    wpdb->insert (/* CODE DATABASE*/);
}
```

So when order status will change to completed for this specific payment methods, this hook will be triggered…

> You can also use instead **`woocommerce_order_status_processing`** if you target **Processing** order status or **`woocommerce_order_status_on-hold`** if you target **On Hold** order status

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

This should works.